# Can I have touch scrolling with gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, touchscreen

Question as title. Is there a way to get gnome-terminal to obey touch scrolling?

I have a touchscreen laptop. Everything else I've tested "just works" (I can scroll web pages by touch using chromium or firefox etc...). Gnome-terminal treats the touch as a select.

---

ubuntu 18.04

```
$ gnome-terminal --version
# GNOME Terminal 3.28.2 using VTE 0.52.2 +GNUTLS -PCRE2
```